# Unable to enable SCM Git Import on Rundeck

Tags: git, version-control, rundeck

When I try to enable Export or Import on Rundeck GUI, it either gives me an error "The request did not include a valid token, or the token has expired. Please try your request again." or send me 500 Bad Request.

I have set `rundeck.security.useHMacRequestTokens=false` in `/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties`. But, no luck.

Please help me in enabling the git export/import

Comment: There is a git issue opened for years, but have not resolved yet https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/960